# Unsatisfied dependency for type org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.session.SearchSession using programmatic mapping in Quarkus Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, quarkus

When I try to use programmatic mapping in Quarkus Hibernate Search, somehow the SearchSession fails to inject.

I was using the annotation based mapping before, and that works fine. I want to switch to programmatic mapping for several reasons, most important is that I need to access Panache id fields. That only works if I at least put an @Indexed at some random entity somewhere, otherwise I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.session.SearchSession and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: app.api.search.SearchDao#searchSession
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[app.api.search.SearchDao, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=app.api.search.SearchDao]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1453)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:311)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:160)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:472)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.session.SearchSession and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: app.api.search.SearchDao#searchSession
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[app.api.search.SearchDao, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=app.api.search.SearchDao]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:478)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:624)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:299)
    ... 13 more
```

When I use the annotations, following e.g. [https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-search-orm-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com), everything works fine.

Removing the annotations, and switching them to a programmatic approach using something like:

```
@SearchExtension
public class SearchConfigurer implements ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurer, HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext context) {
        // we use programmatic mapping instead of annotations since we need to access the panache id as well
        // and we have everything in one place now
        TypeMappingStep product = context.programmaticMapping()
                .type(Product.class);
        product.indexed();
        product.property("id").documentId();
        [...]        

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {

        context.tokenFilter("dutch_stop")
                .type("stop")
                .param("stopwords", "_dutch_");
        context.tokenFilter("dutch_stemmer")
                .type("stemmer")
                .param("language", "dutch");
        context.tokenFilter("dutch_synonyms")
                .type("synonym")
                .param("synonyms", synonyms());
        context.tokenFilter("dutch_decompounder")
                .type("dictionary_decompounder")
                .param("word_list", words());

        context.analyzer("w_dutch").custom()
                .tokenizer("standard")
                .tokenFilters("lowercase", "dutch_stemmer", "dutch_decompounder", "dutch_synonyms");
    }
```

doesn't work. If I then pick a random entity (that I won't be needing for search) and annotate that with @Indexed, everything is fine again.

I also tried naming the SearchConfiguror bean explicitly, using `@Dependent @Named("myMappingConfigurer")` and referencing it in my `application.properties` with:
`quarkus.hibernate-search-orm.mapping.configurer=bean:myMappingConfigurer`. That also didn't work.

I am using Quarkus 3.6.3, with quarkus-hibernate-search-orm-elasticsearch, quarkus-hibernate-orm-rest-data-panache and quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache amongst other dependencies.

Am I missing something?